# Use a Function That Returns Ajax to Ajax.BeginForm's onBegin

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2

EDIT: To be more clear, I am looking to have onBegin call a function that returns a true or false value from an Ajax call. That false value needs to be able to trigger onBegin to abort the form submission, just as if I had returned a false value from a non ajax function.

I need to return a value of false to Ajax.BeginForm's onBegin, if certain conditions exist. This way I can prevent the form from submitting if certain database conditions exist.

However, in order to use the results of an Ajax Get, I would need to craft the function to use callbacks, which means that I cannot have the function used by onBegin return the ajax value. So how can I pass the result into onBegin?

Basically I have:

```
`Ajax.BeginForm(onBegin="checkIfMyConditionExists();"`}...

function checkIfMyConditionExists(){
   $.get(checkConditionURL, function(data){
     doSomething(data);
    });
```

How can I get that data (which would be my true or false value) into onBegin?

Comment: The condition exists server-side, correct?  In that case, wouldn't it make more sense to do the check on the server?

Comment: The condition is server side, however, it can be changed without the UI ever being refreshed as a server roundtrip. I want to be able to check for the condition when they try to submit the form.

Comment: @YHaber Hey I've edited my answer to be quite simple. Check it out if you haven't already.

Comment: What you need to do is restructure your code so that you call the server to get the data you need _first_, and _then_ make that data available to `onBegin`.

Comment: I want to check for it at the onBegin stage because it may have changed between the time the user loaded the UI and when the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish without it being synchronous just is not going to happen. You **WILL** have to perform a synchronous check. Otherwise the check will be called but the form and other things will be submitted before the ajax call has time to say "Wait for me."

In your ajax call to the server you have to set `async: false` on a `$.ajax` call. This will make it to where it will expect some sort of result before running the next bit of code. Keep in mind that you wouldn't want to do `$.get` because there is no option to turn it off.

If you *"don't want the UI to hang"*.... Put some sort of loading icon or text. It's a good practice for "ajax" stuff anyways...

Here is the code you could use :)

```
function checkIfMyConditionExists () {
    $.ajax({
        url: checkConditionURL,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.success) {
                return false;
            }

            // put your code to run something here!
        }
    });
}
```

It really doesn't need to be more complicated than that. Also something to keep in mind when implementing this...

[Per the jQuery.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of  async: false  with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

**Another** way to accomplish this would be to do the following.

Use a standard button on the form. (not a submit)

```
<button id="TriggerButton">Submit</button>
```

Handle the click of that button. Do your check. Submit the form if it's success!

```
$(function () {
    $("#TriggerButton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: checkConditionURL,
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.success) {
                    // ruh roh!
                    return false;
                }

                // submit le form!
                $("#MyForm").trigger("submit");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

With this method, you could remove the onBegin and it should do what you need it to do. :)

Comment: Hi Josh - I specifically don't want to set async to false because of the UI hanging. Does this method somehow avert that?

Comment: No, with how you want to check *first*, you have to somehow stall the form being submitted while checking. The only way you can do that is to either A) Perform a synchronous request and return out of the statement if your check tells you to.. **OR** B) Pull the boolean back to the page on the initial page load and just run a check on that localized variable.

Comment: @YHaber You *DO* realize that what you want to do is not possible without my 2 suggestions in my previous comment or my answer right?

Comment: So there's no way to wire asynchronous callbacks so that they can return a value to the original function? That was what I was looking for and couldn't find.

Comment: You are correct. You will have to restructure your code to perform the asynchronous function first, and then when that returns with the value you can use that value to determine whether to proceed or not.

Comment: @rossipedia and the only way to do that post click is to make it synchronous, as and the others are saying?

Comment: Technically, yes. However I wouldn't suggest you go about it that way, as due to what @joshthecoder said about `async:false` being deprecated I'd suggest restructuring your logic to perform the actual form submit in response to the ajax call, essentially inverting your logic.

Comment: @rossipedia If I follow your suggestion to invert the logic, I wouldn't be able to use MVC's ajax form at all. I would have to look for onClick or onSubmit, preventDefault, and then based on the callbacks from the Javascript, either submit the form or display the appropriate feedback to the user. Correct?

Comment: Yes. I have a lengthy explanation that I will post as an answer.

Comment: The form itself still needs to be Ajax, because the way the UI works, all this happens in the background, and different divs react to the new content. That's one reason I was so loath to ditch the MVC Ajax. I would have to handle onSuccess of the main form on my own too, even though it's fully functional now. I was hoping to add this check by just dropping it in onBegin.

Comment: I'm kind of laughing at this situation only because I've been here more times than I can remember. I think I might have a working solution to keep the Ajax Form. Editing my answer. :)

Comment: @YHaber Hey, the bounty is in the grace period now. Did you end up getting my solution to work?

Answer (score 2):

I modified your code with a solution that works:

```
Ajax.BeginForm(onBegin="return checkIfMyConditionExists();"}...

function checkIfMyConditionExists(){  
    $.ajax({
    url: checkConditionURL,
    data: data,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        return data.condition;
    }
});
```

note the  async: false option that allows you to wait until the call ends and get the results after that.

Comment: Maurizio - See my note on the bounty, where I stated that I am looking for a solution that does not make it synchronous, as that locks up the UI thread. Does this solution avert that?

Comment: Your problem in unsolvable the way you want it. The OnBegin method is called just before the call to the action is made, meaning after the user click the submit button. In order to check your condition you need to wait for the answer from the DB. So the sequence of events here is: 1. user clikc submit, 2. you check your database if he can do it, 3. wait for an answer, 4. submit or cancel the request.

Comment: If you want to avoid the user to wait after he click the submit button you have to make your call to the DB onLoad of you document (it shoudl still be syncronous though to be 100% sure) and store the answer in a variable that you will then use in your onBegin. That is the only way I can see to minimize UI lock.

Answer (score 0):

### *My Working code*

**JavaScript/JQuery**

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function StartValidation() {
        var result = AjaxCall();
        return result;
    }
    function AjaxCall() {
        var Istrue = false;
        $.ajax({
            url         :   "@Url.Action("Json", "FileUpload")",
            contentType :   "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType    :   "json",
            type        :   "POST",
            data        :   JSON.stringify({FirstName:'test', LastName:'test1'})
        }).done(function() { 
             Istrue = true; 
             alert('ok') 
        })
        .fail(function() {
             Istrue = false; 
             alert('not ok'); 
        });
        return Istrue;
    }
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UploadRequestFile", "FileUpload", new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "return StartValidation();"
    }, new { id = "frmUp" }))
{
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**Runtime MarkUp**

```
<form method="post" id="frmUp" data-ajax-method="POST" 
      data-ajax-begin="return StartValidation();" data-ajax="true" 
      action="/fileupload/UploadRequestFile?Length=10">            
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Check the data-ajax-method, data-ajax-begin and data-ajax attributes. Ajax.BeginForm helper emits those attributes. Those attributes mean absolutely nothing to the browser. It's the jquery.unobtrsuive-ajax.js script that understands and interprets them. Without it. So, no need to perform the Submit explicitly.

**Action Methods**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Json(string FirstName, String LastName)
{
    //Do the Validation Part here.
    return Json(new { Success = true });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadRequestFile()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Approach 1 isn't going to work at all. By the time the callback provided to `done()` is called, `CheckServerConditions()` has already returned `undefined`, which is false-y and the form will never post.

Comment: @rossipedia - Sorry, May be I am wrong. I think, u misunderstood the Approach - 1... We have two Callbacks.  `Success` Callback and `Error Callback` under `CheckServerConditions` function. Which are returning `Boolean` values. My question is - How should the `CheckServerConditions` function return `undefined` in any scenario ? I made some changes in `CheckServerConditions` function to make it more clear. Thanks for the time.

Comment: The issue is that it doesn't seem as if you understand how the asynchronous nature of javascript works. It's too long to explain in a comment, so I've created a jsfiddle with comments to explain what's going on: http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/pR25d/

Comment: If you're trying to handle `OnSubmit`, then your revised example suffers from the same problem.

Comment: @rossipedia : No. Please tell me the problem in code. This time it is fine :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32362/discussion-between-rossipedia-and-pkkg)